# Submitting an HTML form using WebView for Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm somewhat new to Android and I'm having a problem with submitting an HTML form using WebView.

I'm trying to download a YouTube video (I know it's illegal! I'm doing this for the sake of practice) by inputting the video url in a form of a website that already exists.

I also need to click the submit button.

Below is my code which doesn't seem to do anything.

```
    String javascript = "javascript: {"
        + "document.getElementById('aurl').value = " + videoUrl + ";"
        + "var button = document.getElementsByName('asubmit');"
        + "button.click(); }";
    webView.loadUrl(javascript);
```

Answer (score 3):

Compare a WebView with the iFrame Element where you just take a URL and put it into a special view. So if im understanding you correctly your form already works as standalone website. So just replace the String in loadUrl(...) with the URL of your form and it should work fine.

If you want Javascript in your webview, you can enable it like this:

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by replacing the string with the url of the form.. [link](http://auderio.com/) this is the website I'm using!

Comment: Ok I solved my problem! It was just a syntax error haha